# Getting Error when Previewing Oracle tables in SQL Data Tools 2017 SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ssis

Im using **SSIS** package which created **SQL Sever data tools 2017** to load data from **Oracle** to **SQL Server**. I have setup the Oracle Client 32bit in SQL Sever and configure tnsnames.ora correctly. In OLE DB data source at Data Flow Task successfully connected to Orcal Database in SSIS. I have try simple query out some columns using **SQL Command** in **OLE DB Source**.
But Im getting following error when previewing the data,**provider cannot derive parameter information and setparameterinfo has not been called. (Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle).**
I have tested packages which created in SQL data tools 2010,2012,2014 and those are worked fine and not generated any errors. But for 2015 and 2017 SQL Data tool packages above mentioned error is generating. So could you guide me how to fix this in SQL Data Tools 2017 version.

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: RightClick on Project -> Open Properties ->Debugging -> Run 64BitRuntime -> False

Comment: I have executed package on 64bit Runtime false and true also. Both of time that above mentioned error popping out.

Comment: Have you tried using the Attunity Connectors? There are different versions for different SQL Server versions. I think you'd need 5.0 for SSDT 2017. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/attunity-connectors?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014